# Unit testing code with Google Cloud API dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, go, google-cloud-storage

I'm writing a small slack bot which helps my developers get DB dumps from Google Cloud SQL. I've written it using https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go packages heavily, but now I've stumbled in writing unit tests. I want to opensource the code for others to use, but want to contribute something that follows basic guidelines, i.e. has test coverage.

I've read a lot about mocking, using interfaces, and that google library is notorious for being a pain to use in tests, and that Google people look down on mocking. But still can't make first step to writing tests, piece of code for example:

```
type StorageClient struct {
    client       *storage.Client
    targetBucket string
    Logger       *log.Logger
    context      context.Context
}
...
// Accepts name of object to be published, makes it world readable and returns its public URL as a string
func (c *StorageClient) PublishDumpFile(name string) (string, error) {
    obj := c.client.Bucket(c.targetBucket).Object(name)
    err := obj.ACL().Set(c.context, storage.AllUsers, storage.RoleReader)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("http://storage.googleapis.com/%s/%s", c.targetBucket, name), nil
}
```

Notice the cascading calls like Bucket().Object() and such, each returns new struct, so to mock it I'd need to define for each one a corresponding interface and create logic inside my test that will somewhat resemble logic behind google package (Bucket() returns struct which belongs to interface which has Object() method which returns... etc). But at this point I'm thinking I'm approaching it from wrong perspective.

I'm new to this ecosystem and testing such high-level things, so any help appreciated.

Comment: Not really a direct solution but check out the recently released [go-cloud](https://github.com/google/go-cloud).

Comment: @Adrian it doesn't look stable yet and also lacks functionality I need, mainly support for cloudsql admin API

Comment: Unit tests should test functions without side effects, if your'e testing a function that calls storage you're really running an integration test which if you're to test it properly needs to actually call the real service. Is it not possible to test against Google Cloud using a test bucket? Then there's no mocking required.

Comment: @KennyGrant I can do real bucket and real SQL internally on my infrastructure, but was intending to opensource this code

Comment: I think that's fine personally - to use the code you need GCS access, so to test it (with integration tests), you need access too... the alternative is really just testing a vast array of complex mocks which is too fragile and not *really* testing anything at all except your code + some code written solely with your code in mind.

Comment: @KennyGrant thank you, that's what I was arriving at myself, but being a newbie in this ecosystem wanted to hear another opinion

Comment: May I ask you to post this two comments as an answer, @KennyGrant ? They are kind of good and relevant, and as comments are 'volatile', anything good should be 'translated' to an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests should test functions without side effects, if you are testing a function that calls storage you're really running an integration test which if you're to test it properly needs to actually call the real service. Is it not possible to test against Google Cloud using a test bucket? Then there's no mocking required.

To use the code you need GCS access, so to test it (with integration tests), you need access too. The alternative is really just testing a vast array of complex mocks which is too fragile and not really testing anything at all except your code + some code written solely with your code in mind.